# Question about weak Convergence and Portmanteau theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

$F_n \Rightarrow F$ on the real line if and only if for each $x$
$$\liminf F_n(x) \leq F(x)$$ and $$\liminf F_n(x-0) \geq F(x-0)$$.

I know that by Portmanteau's theorem second condition on the "if part" implies weak convergence and vice versa.

I didn't understand why we need the first condition in the "if part" and vise versa.

Comment: By definition of weak convergence, we need $\lim_{n\to \infty}F_n(x)=F(x)$ for all $x$ where $F$ is continuous. If $x$ is indeed a continuity point of $F$, then $F(x-0)=F(x)$. Thus we get $F(x-0)=F(x)\leq \lim\inf F_n(x-0)\leq \lim\inf F_n(x)\leq F(x)$. This shows that $\lim F_n(x)=F(x)$. On the other hand, assume the weak convergence and notice that $\lim\inf F_n(x-0)=\lim\infPr(X_n<x)\geq P(X<x)=F(x-0)$. Similarly you get the first inequality by considering the set $Pr(X_n\leq x)$ and applying Portmanteau's lemma.

Comment: How exactly do you use Prokhorov's theorem is not clear. Prokhorov's theorem only tells you when a family of measure is relatively compact (wrt topology of weak convergence). I am not aware of Prokhorov's theorem giving us the condition for the weak convergence.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho my bad!!...its Portmanteau Theorem...I edited the question...and thanks.

Comment: Aah! That's okay. You have to be a bit careful. In Portmanteau's theorem generally you will be working with a larger class of functions. For example, it would say that it is necessary and sufficient to check that $\lim\inf E(f(X_n))\geq E(f(X))$ for {\emph all lower semi-continuous function that are bounded below}. Here we are working essentially with characteristic functions, so one direction will follow from Portmanteu's theorem. But to prove that the condition is enough for the week convergence, you need both the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F_n$ converges to $F$ weakly. By Portmanteau's theorem, you can get ofcourse both the conditions.

Now suppose you are given that $1) \lim\inf F_n(x)\leq F(x)$ and $2) \liminf F_n(x-0)\geq F(x-0)$. Notice that only the condition, say, $2)$ is not enough to apply Portmanteau's theorem because It will require you to check that $3) \lim\inf P(X_n\in U)\geq P(X\in U)$ for `every open set'. From the condition $2)$, you will get it only for the open sets of the form $(-\infty, x)$ (and possibly a little more with a little bit of massaging, I didn't give it much thought).

But every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable union of disjoint open intervals. Therefore, if we could prove that $\lim\inf P(X_n\in (a, b))\geq P(X\in (a, b))$ for all $a<b\in \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm\infty\},$ then we will be done.

If $a=-\infty$, we are done. This is precisely the condition $2)$. Suppose $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $P(X_n\in (a, b))=P(X_n<b)-P(X_n\leq a)$. What we get therefore is that

$$\lim\inf P(X_n\in (a, b))=\lim\inf P(X_n<b)-\limsup P(X_n\leq a).$$

This should give us some idea why we need condition $1)$. Remember that our goal is to show something like $$\lim\inf P(X_n<b)-\limsup P(X_n\leq a)\geq P(X\in (a, b))=P(X<b)-P(X\leq a).$$ This suggests that we should add another condition $$2^*) \quad F(a)=P(X\leq a)\geq \limsup P(X_n\leq a)=\limsup F_n(a).$$

This condition is slightly stronger than what you have written. To get exactly your condition, one can observe that $$\lim\inf P(X_n<b)-\limsup P(X_n\leq a)\geq \lim\inf P(X_n<b)-\liminf P(X_n\leq a).$$
It is therefore sufficient to show that $$\lim\inf P(X_n<b)-\liminf P(X_n\leq a)\geq P(X<b)-P(X\leq a).$$
With condition $2)$, it is enough therefore to assume $1)$.